# How to create a minesweeper board in javascript?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, minesweeper

I am using div elements to create minesweeper board (8 x 8 or whatever). I used 2 for loops to create the board of divs

```
window.onload = function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            var elem = document.createElement('div');
            container.appendChild(elem);
            elem.className = 'myclass';
        }
        var breaker = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(breaker);
        breaker.className = 'clear';
    }
}
```

Everything is nicely displayed but i can't figure out how to track the position of every tile (div), like a (x,y) coordinate system, so later i can do the game logic based on these coordinates. 
So how can i map this grid system?

Comment: give them data attributes `elem.setAttribute('data-x', j); elem.setAttribute('data-y', i)`

Comment: While beyond the scope of this question, the [intro to react.js](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) tutorial goes through creating a tic-tac-toe game in React.js. If you aren't afraid to dig a bit into more advanced approaches it might be an interesting project to modify [the code for this example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR?editors=0010#0) into something matching your minesweeper idea. Anyway, you can see there how they represent a 3x3 board by numbering sequentially from 0 to 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Element.setAttribute` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to add custom attributes to your elements:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      var elem = document.createElement('div');
      container.appendChild(elem);
      elem.className = 'myclass';
      elem.setAttribute('data-row', i);
      elem.setAttribute('data-col', j);
    }
    var breaker = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(breaker);
    breaker.className = 'clear';
  }
}
```

```css
.myclass{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.clear{
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
       <div id="container">
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar for a project and I used data-attributes to hold the "coordinates" and would refer to the data-attribute whenever I needed the coords. Here is my function.

Creates the divs based on maxRow and maxColumn

```
function createDivs(maxRow) {

var wrapperDiv = document.getElementById("mazeWrapper");
var rowDiv;
  for (var i=0; i < maxRow; i++) {
      var thisDiv = document.createElement("div");
  thisDiv.id = "mazeRow-" + i;
  thisDiv.className = "row";
    wrapperDiv.appendChild(thisDiv);
    for (var j=0; j < maxColumn; j++) {
      rowDiv = document.getElementById("mazeRow-" + i);
          var thisColumnDiv = document.createElement("div");
            thisColumnDiv.id = (i*maxRow)+j;               
            thisColumnDiv.className = "mazehole";
            rowDiv.appendChild(thisColumnDiv);
            //Adding in a html data-set to hold X,Y values for coordinate system
            var elemID = (thisColumnDiv.id).toString();
            var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
            var att = document.createAttribute("data-coords");
            att.value = j+","+i;
            elem.setAttributeNode(att);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: The reason I did this was to have available to me both a number (that was the ID for the div) and a coord (x,y) for each div so that I could use either as needed throughout my application.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can store the position of every `<div>` element (x and y coordinates) as 'data' attributes.

Example:

```
elem.setAttribute('data-x', i);
elem.setAttribute('data-y', j);
```

You could use getAttribute() later to read the value of the data attributes.

Example:

```
var x = elem.getAttribute('data-x');
var y = elem.getAttribute('data-y');
```

Or even in an easier way:

```
var x = elem.dataset.x;
var y = elem.dataset.y;
```

See [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) from MDN for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As you create elements, give each one a unique name.  For example `elem.id = 'row' + i + 'col' + j;`

You can then later use `document.getElementById( ... )`

Comment: I tried something like that but it's kinda difficult because the id = 'row' + i + 'col' + j will be a string, and if i want move right on the row i cant just increase the row number by 1 because id is a string.

Comment: true.  @xavvier's answer using data attributes is better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it's coordinates (x:y) as the id of each block.
You can also write it with a single loop.

```js
function blockClick(event){
  const selected = document.querySelector('#board .block.selected');
  if(selected != null){
    selected.classList.remove('selected');
  }
  document.querySelector('#coords').innerHTML = this.id;
  this.classList.add('selected');
}

function createBoard(cols, rows, blockSize){

  this._boardDom = document.getElementById('board');
  const noBlocks = cols * rows;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < noBlocks; i++){
    
    const block = document.createElement('div');
    const y = Math.ceil((i + 1)/rows);
    const x = (i + 1) - ((y - 1)*rows);
    block.id = `${x}:${y}`
    // block.innerHTML = `${x}:${y}`; // uncomment this to render x:y
    block.style.width = `${blockSize}px`;
    block.style.height = `${blockSize}px`;
    block.classList.add('block');
    
    block.addEventListener('click', blockClick);
    
    this._boardDom.appendChild(block);
  
  }
  
  this._boardDom.style.width = `${(blockSize*cols) + 2*(rows)}px`

}

createBoard(8,8,30)
```

```css
#board{
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#board .block{
  border: solid gray 1px;
}

#board .block.selected{
  border: solid gray 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Click on an element to see its coordinates
</div>
<div id="coords">
</div>
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had fun creating this so I wanted to share. I used SVG because they are flexible and easy to generate.

These are the BaseBoard loops:

https://bgwest.github.io/websweeper/

```
// MakeBaseBoard.js

// named export - genGuiBoard
var genGuiBaseBoard = function(lastRow, lastCol, gameBoardWidth, gameBoardHeight) {
  // make base elements and attributes
  var boardTiles = document.getElementById("board");
  var tile = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  var squareElem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
  var textElem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
  // define square with and set loop values to 0
  var width = 20;
  var height = width;
  var row = 0;
  var col = 0;
  var xcord = 0;
  var ycord = 0;
  // text element coords
  var textXcord = 6;
  var textYcord = 15;
  // board
  tile.setAttribute("width", `${gameBoardWidth}`);
  tile.setAttribute("height", `${gameBoardHeight}`);
  tile.setAttribute("id", "gameBoard");

  boardTiles.appendChild(tile);
  // row
  for (row = 0; row < lastRow; row++) {
    // col
    for (col = 0; col < lastCol; col++) {
      // rect
      var squareElem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
      squareElem.setAttribute("class", "game-squares");
      squareElem.setAttribute("data-rowIndex", `${row}`)
      squareElem.setAttribute("data-colIndex", `${col}`)
      squareElem.setAttribute("id", `row${row}col${col}`);
      squareElem.setAttribute("width", `${width}px`);
      squareElem.setAttribute("height", `${height}px`);
      squareElem.setAttribute("x", `${xcord}`);
      squareElem.setAttribute("y", `${ycord}`);
      squareElem.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
      squareElem.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1");
      squareElem.setAttribute("stroke-opacity", "0.7");
      squareElem.setAttribute("fill", "#b1bcce");
      squareElem.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "0.5");    
      tile.appendChild(squareElem);
      // generate text elements with base style but wait to add Bombs
      var textElem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
      textElem.setAttribute("class", `text-squares`);
      textElem.setAttribute("data-rowIndex", `${row}`)
      textElem.setAttribute("data-colIndex", `${col}`)
      textElem.setAttribute("id", `text-id-row${row}col${col}`);
      textElem.setAttribute("x", `${textXcord}`);
      textElem.setAttribute("y", `${textYcord}`);
      textElem.setAttribute("font-size", "1.0em");
      // text elements are placed invisibily and event handles are laid later
      textElem.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "0.0");
      textElem.innerHTML = `#`;
      tile.appendChild(textElem);
      // looping vars
      xcord+=width;
      textXcord+=width;
    }
    // reset x
    xcord=0;
    textXcord=6;
    // continue y
    ycord+=width;
    textYcord+=width;
  }
}

export { genGuiBaseBoard };
```

https://github.com/bgwest/websweeper/blob/master/components/MakeBaseBoard.js

The bombs and numbers are then placed in SetBoard.js. The other modules (components) can be found in the link below.

https://github.com/bgwest/websweeper